# スペースを含んだファイルパス存在するか確かめたい

Tags: linux, shellscript

`~/Library/Application Support/`

のようにスペースを含んだファイルパスを

```
$ path="~/Library/Application Support/"
$ [ -e "$path" ] && echo Found || echo Not Found
```

のように存在するか判定したいのですが、これを実行すると

`Not Found`

とファイルおよびディレクトリが見つからなかったと表示されてしまいます。
スペースを含んだファイルパスが存在するかどうか確かめるうまい方法はありませんか

Comment: 回答していただいたコマンドはファイルパスが存在するかどうかの判定にはならないため、回答しやすくなるように内容の内容をすこし変えました。

Comment: 元の質問文ではスペースを含んだファイルパスの扱いに問題があり、それはtake88さんの回答で直ったのですが、ダブルクォートで囲んだことで `~` が展開されないという別の問題に変わりました。そして最終的に、変数 `path` に設定する時点で（ダブルクォート内でも展開される） `$HOME` を使うことで解決した、という流れですね。今の質問文ではtake88さんの回答が的外れに見えてしまうので、質問文を書き換えるのではなく、追記していただけるとよかったかと思います。

Comment: たしかに・・・別問題にすりかわってますね。

Comment: @take88 さんの回答にコメントを追記しておきます

Comment: @take88 さんの回答に追記しました

Comment: 言葉足らずで申し訳ないですが、**あなたの質問文に**追記、つまり「元の質問文」と「take88さんの回答を試したが解決しなかった」ということを両方質問文に残してほしかった、という話です。これならtake88さんの回答も依然有効ですよね？（仮に質問が大きく変わってしまい、古い回答を残さないべきと思うなら、編集ではなく別の質問として投稿した方がよいかもしれません）

Comment: うーん？？？
それはあなたの意見ですよね。なんかそういうデータでもあるんですか？

Comment: 私の感覚に基づいて個人的に提案しただけです。もっと大きく変更されたケースについては他の方々による議論もありました（http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1558/8000）が、今回ぐらいなら何も問題ないという見方もあるかと思います。

Comment: ちょっとまってくださいね。このURLしっかりみてみます

Comment: 裏付けのデータしっかりありますね。これは参ったな・・・。とにかく今回いけなかったのは「投票結果の意味が失われる」という点だと思いますね。好意であれエゴの主張であれ、とにかく誰かが無知な僕に光を示してくれたのは確かなことですし。ここではなるべく大きな変更をする場合は別の質問にしようと思います。ところでなんですが、この質問を編集するまえに「別の質問を作ろうかな」と思いましたが、よく考えて別の質問を作らずにこの質問そのものを編集することにしました。なぜなら今回、回答をくれた @take88 さんの回答が少なからず的外れだったからです。今回の質問のゴールは「スペースをパス名に含みながらも実在するパス名だった場合は true を返す」という感じのものでした。しかし@take88 のコマンドでは「実在しているのに false を返す」という的はずれなものでした。ですので質問の内容がいけないのだと感じ、別に質問を作ることなく、質問の内容そのものを編集しました。かなりややこしいとおもわれました？　ところがどっこい！　意外に自分のやりたいほうだいしているわけじゃなかったみたいなんですヨ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test -e "$HOME/Library/Application Support/"`

これでどうでしょう。

Comment: `test -e "~/Library/Application Support/" && echo Found || echo Not Found ` では 

`Not Found` でしたが `test -e "$HOME/Library/Application Support/"  && echo Found || echo Not Found` では `Found` でした。解決しました＼(^o^)／

Answer (score 5):

ダブルクォートで囲まれた内部で `~(tilde)` が展開されない事について少し。

> **bash(1)**
>
> **QUOTING**
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes **preserves the literal value** of all characters within the quotes, **with the exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is enabled, !**.

```
$ echo ~
/home/nemo
$ echo "~"
~
```

上記は bash についてですが、POSIX complient な shell 全てに当てはまります。

[Shell Command Language - 2.2.3 Double-Quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03)

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/21067/%E3%83%81%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80-%E3%81%A8-home-%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB

Comment: これはみなさんわからなそうな豆知識ですので、新しい質問として作りましt。上記URLで回答をしていただけたら多くの方々にとって嬉しい物に鳴ると思います(｀･ω･´)ゞ

Answer (score 1):

変数をクオートで囲みます。

```
$ test -e "$path"
```

（追記）

「~」が展開されないというご指摘が有ったので別解として書きます。

```
$ path="~/Library/Application Support/"
$ ls -1 "$path" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "Found" || echo "Not Found"
```

わかりにくければ eval を使うと `~` を展開出来ます。

```
[ -e "$(eval "echo $path")" ] && echo "Found" || echo "Not Found"
```

Comment: `[ -e "$path" ] && echo Found || echo Not Found`

とやっても `Not Found` になってしまうので `test -e "$path`では問題の解決にはならないようでした

Comment: 他の方々とやり取りをしているうちに質問の内容がすこし変わってしまいました。この回答は質問に対する的確な解決法にならない可能性があります。削除、もしくは回答の変更を推奨します。せっかく回答していただいたのにもうしわけありませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

すでに回答があるようにダブルクォートでエスケープするとチルダ展開は実行されないので、次のようにしましょう。

```
$ path=~"/Library/Application Support/"
$ [ -e "$path" ] && echo Found || echo Not Found
```

この書き方ならば、自分以外のユーザーでも OK です。

```
$ path=~username"/Library/Application Support/"
$ [ -e "$path" ] && echo Found || echo Not Found
```