# チルダ と $HOME の違いってなんでしょうか？

Tags: bash, sh, shellscript, zsh

チルダと$HOME では出力結果が違うのはなぜ？

`$ test -e "~/Library/Application Support/" && echo Found || echo Not Found`

**`Not Found`**

`$ test -e "$HOME/Library/Application Support/" && echo Found || echo Not Found`

**`Found`**

**以下の回答からこの質問が生まれました。**

> 「ダブルクォートで囲まれた内部で ~(tilde) が展開されない事について少し。」
>   https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/21065/14041
>
> ```
> $ echo ~
> /home/nemo
> $ echo "~"
> ~
> ```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`~`は例えばbashで[Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)の一つ、[Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html)で、自分や他人のホームディレクトリに展開されます。

> **If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (‘~’)**, all of the characters up to the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.

とあり`""`で括られると条件を満たさなくなります。

`$HOME`は同じくShell Expansionsの一つ、[Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)で、シェル変数・環境変数の値が展開されます。こちらは`~`のような制限はなさそうです。