# EC2に設定したcronでgoファイルを実行すると他ファイルを読み込めない

Tags: aws, go, amazon-ec2, cron

毎週日曜日の22時になったらGoスクリプトを実行するcronをEC2上に設定しました。

時刻になるとこのようなエラーが出て処理が止まってしまうのですが、原因がわかりません。

後述しますが、cronで設定したコマンドを直打ちすると動作するのに対し、cronとして設定すると動作しない点に悩んでおります。

```
Failed to read CSV file open sample.csv: no such file or directory
※ csvファイルをmain.goから読み込めなかった場合に、コンソールにこのエラーが出力されるようにしています
```

以下が詳細な状況になります。知見ある方がいらっしゃいましたらご助言頂きたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

### 状況

- `crontab -e` でcronを登録
- cronが実行できていることは確認済み
- 実行後、`/var/spool/mail/ec2-user` に上記のエラーが書き込み
- cronで指定したコマンドを直打ちした場合は問題なく動作する

#### 実行結果

```
# cronの確認
[ec2-user@ip-xxx]$ crontab -l => 00 13 * * SUN /usr/bin/go run ~/go/src/project_name/main.go

# crondの確認
[ec2-user@ip-xxx]$ service crond status => Active: active (running) since xxxx Main PID xxxx(crond)

# cron の実行の確認
22時前
[ec2-user@ip-xxx]$ sudo less /var/log/cron | grep main => 何も表示されず
22時
[ec2-user@ip-xxx]$ sudo less /var/log/cron | grep main => Nov 1 13:00:01 ip-xx-x-x-xxx CROND[xxxxx]: (ec2-user) CMD (/usr/bin/go run ~/go/src/project_name/main.go)

# cron の出力を確認
[ec2-user@ip-xxx]$ sudo less /var/spool/mail/ec2-user => Failed to read CSV file open sample.csv: no such file or directory

# cron で指定したコマンドを直打ち
[ec2-user@ip-xxx]$ /usr/bin/go run ~/go/src/project_name/main.go => 期待通りの出力
```

### 試したこと

- `~/go/src/project_name/main.go` の代わりに `~/go/src/project_name` を実行したが挙動は変わらず
- `os.Open("sample.csv")` を `os.Open("~/go/src/project_name/sample.csv")` に変更しても変わらず

### 実行対象のGoファイル

```
func main() {
    err, names, codes := readCSV("sample.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err, token, secret, id, _ := loadEnv()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@/db_name")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // 上記のデータを使って処理開始
}


// csv読み込み
func readCSV(fileName string) (err error, names []string, codes []string) {
    f, err := os.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Failed to read CSV file", err)
        return err, nil, nil
    }

    r := csv.NewReader(f)
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Failed to read CSV record", err)
            return err, nil, nil
        }

        codes = append(codes, record[0])
        names = append(names, name+"テスト")
    }
    return nil, names, codes

}

// 環境変数読み込み
func loadEnv() (err error, token string, secret string, id string, sheetId string) {
    err = godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Failed to load .env file", err)
        return err, "", "", "", ""
    }
    token = os.Getenv("token")
    secret = os.Getenv("secret")
    id = os.Getenv("id")
    sheetId = os.Getenv("sheetId")

    return nil, token, secret, id, sheetId
}
```

### ディレクトリ構成

project_name

- main.go
- sample.csv
- schools

  - school.go
- .env

### 環境

- EC2(無料枠)

  - t2.micro
  - Amazon Linux 2 AMI
  - MySQLの設定完了(RDSは使わない)
  - GOPATHは`~/go`に設定

Comment: 質問しっぱなしで放置せず、[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)に沿って対応してください。

Comment: 失礼致しました。先日お答え頂いた回答をリンクを参考にして承認させて頂きました。質問への回答だけでなく、自分が確認できていなかったサービスの利用法までご指導いただきまして、本当にありがとうございます！以降は改善いたします。

Comment: `main.go` で `sample.csv` を open する際に、`sample.csv` のファイルパスを相対パスにしていませんか？ 例えば `os.Open("sample.csv")` の様にです。

Comment: @metropolis まさしくそのように記述しておりました。しかし、相対パスではなく`os.Open("~/go/src/project_name/sample.csv" )` にしても挙動が変わりませんでした。

Comment: `os.Open("~/go/src/project_name/sample.csv" )` ですが、`~`(チルダ)はシェルが解釈するものなので挙動が変化しないのはその通りです。具体的には`os.Open(filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HOME"), "go/src/project_name/sample.csv"))` とします。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます、上手く動作致しました！csv, .env ファイルを読み込む方法に加え、チルダ(~)の解釈も勉強になりました。アンサーとしてマークしたいと思いますので、回答として書いていただけると幸甚です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `os.Open("sample.csv")` を `os.Open("~/go/src/project_name/sample.csv")` に変更しても変わらず

`~`(tilde,チルダ)に関しては以下の回答で詳しく述べられていますので参照して下さい。

[チルダ と $HOME の違いってなんでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/21068/16894)

`~` という文字はシェルにおいては特殊な意味を持つ場合がありますが、golang では `~` という文字そのものでしかありませんので、置き換える必要があります。具体的には実ユーザ(この場合は `ec2-user`)のホームディレクトリに相当しますので、環境変数 `HOME` を使います。

```golang
os.Open(filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HOME"), "go/src/project_name/sample.csv"))
```

**crontab(5)**

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon. SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the /etc/passwd line of the crontab's owner.

ところで、本題とは関係ありませんが、以下の事が少し気になっています。

- `go build` で作成した実行形式ファイルではなく、`go run` でプログラムを実行している
- CSV ファイルのパスをプログラムの中に直接記述している(`hard coding`)

`go build` で作成した実行形式ファイルを使うのであれば、`filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HOME"), "go/src/project_name/sample.csv")` などとしなくても済むのですが。。。